# How to add a UserProperty to an Outlook appointmentItem

Tags: .net, outlook

I am developing an outlook addin and I am trying to add a UserProperty to an appointmentItem. But the first time I get an UnauthorizedAccessException. When I call the method a second time, it works and the UserProperty is successfully added to the appointment. The problem occured after I changed the name of the Property. Do I have to register the property somehow or do something else before adding this property?

```
Appointment.AddCustomProperty(AppointmentItem, "CRMConKat", OlUserPropertyType.olText, cat.katName)
```

Comment: Calling the line a second time actually works...

Answer (score 0):

There is no AddUserProperty method. Do you mean you call AppointmentItem.UserProperties.Add?
Can you modify any other appointment properties?
Do you get this error on all appointments?
How is the appointment opened?
How did you change the name of the property? Do you mean it was already set before?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I mean the UserProperties.Add() method. It is called in our AddCustomProperty() method. I renamed one of the Properties I added and after this renaming this error occured everytime I call this method also when I try to add another property. Before it was called "CRMConKat1" and now "CRMConKat" I create this appointment with the Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) method.

Comment: Are you sure a property with that name but different type does not already exist? Can you add a property with a different name?